# React typescript pass props interface to the class component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have components:

```
interface IComponentAProps {
  sameData: string;
  data: IDataA;
  callback: (data: IDataA) => void;
}

class ComponentA extends Component<IComponentAProps> {
  render() {
  // ...
  }
}

// and in other component:

render() 
  return (<ComponentA callback={...} sameData={...} data={data} />);
}
```

How to pass IComponentAProps to ComponentA? To use it more generic? I don't want to create another component to do this:

```
interface IComponentBProps {
  sameData: string;
  data: IDataB;
  callback: (data: IDataB) => void;
}

class ComponentB extends Component<IComponentBProps> {
  render() {
  // ...
  }
}

// and in other component:

render() 
  return (<ComponentB callback={...} sameData={...} data={data} />);
}
```

Can I do something like this?

```
class ComponentA<T> extends Component<T & IComponentAProps> 

interface INewInterface {
  data: INewData;
  callback: (data: INewData) => void;
}

// and in other component:

render() 
  return (<ComponentA<INewInterface> callback={...} sameData={...} data={data} />);
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you wrote, I assume you want two components to share a similar interface.

Both components share the same blueprint — it's only the shape of `data` that differs. That's a good use case for generic props.

```
interface Props<T> {
  sameData: string;
  data: T;
  callback: (data: T) => void;
}

declare class MyComponent<T> extends Component<Props<T>> {}
```

Such a component can now be used with any `data`.

```
const user = {
  name: 'Bob',
};

<MyComponent<typeof user>
  data={user}
  sameData="potato"
  callback={data => console.log(data.name)}
/>;

const animal = {
  species: 'dog',
};

<MyComponent<typeof animal>
  data={animal}
  sameData="potato"
  callback={data => console.log(data.species)}
/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add this interface into your `interfaces.d.ts` it will be accessible through the whole application.

But in this case, I think it's better to export the interface in the ComponentA and import it in the ComponentB.

Answer (score 0):

You can create common interface and extend it in your components:

```js
// file with common types
export interface IComponentCommonProps {
  sameData: string;
}

//file with component A
import {IComponentCommonProps} from 'FILE_WITH_COMMON_TYPES';

interface IComponentAProps extends IComponentCommonProps {
  data: INewData;
  callback: (data: INewData) => void;
}

class ComponentA extends Component<IComponentAProps> {
  render() {
  // ...
  }
}



//file with component B
import {IComponentCommonProps} from 'FILE_WITH_COMMON_TYPES';

interface IComponentBProps extends IComponentCommonProps {
  data: INewData;
  callback: (data: INewData) => void;
}

class ComponentB extends Component<IComponentAProps> {
  render() {
  // ...
  }
}

// another component
render() 
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentA callback={...} sameData={...} data={data} />
      <ComponentB callback={...} sameData={...} data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```